# Unable to compile HTML in uib.popover in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-components

I am using the official Bootstrap UI for Angular and I'm having problem rendering expressions in template of ui.bootstrap.popover.

Here's a component in my HTML:

```
<edit-button url="myurl.php" form="myNewForm"></edit-button>
```

It's template is as follows:

```
<button uib-popover-template="app/edit.html"></button>
```

And, here's `edit.html`:

```
{{1+1}}
```

I'm receiving this error:

> unrecognized expression: {{1+1}}

What do I do? What's the problem here? I'm actually trying to use [SchemaForm](http://schemaform.io) directives instead of {{1+1}}.

Comment: Try wrapping `{{1 + 1 }}` in a div. From the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover): "Note that the contents of this template need to be wrapped in a tag, e.g., <div></div>". Also, are you sure the template is being resolved? Looks like you need single quotes around `app/edit.html`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the template inside simple quotes, like this:

```
<button uib-popover-template="'app/edit.html'"></button>
```